# Twitter Trends API 1.1 error "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, ios6

Take a look at my code below:

```
NSError *jsonParsingError;
NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
NSArray *trends = jsonResults[@"trends"]; //error on this line
```

I encounter an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

The url i use is: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1

Take a look at the jsonResults value:

[image: Take a look at the jsonResults value]

Compared to the TwitterSearch (a sample application) results:

[image: Compared to the TwitterSearch results]

here is the logged value of the jsonResults variable:

```
2013-08-26 11:05:44.489 TwitterTrends[48410:490b] JSON: (
        {
        "as_of" = "2013-08-26T03:04:24Z";
        "created_at" = "2013-08-26T02:51:26Z";
        locations =         (
                        {
                name = Worldwide;
                woeid = 1;
            }
        );
        trends =         (
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "#chupaedu";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%23chupaedu";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23chupaedu";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "#VMA2013NAMTV";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%23VMA2013NAMTV";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23VMA2013NAMTV";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "#YoConfiesoQue";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%23YoConfiesoQue";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23YoConfiesoQue";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "#MiObsesionPor";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%23MiObsesionPor";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23MiObsesionPor";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "#LasMejoresPeliculasQueViFueron";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%23LasMejoresPeliculasQueViFueron";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23LasMejoresPeliculasQueViFueron";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "Emile Sande";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%22Emile+Sande%22";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Emile+Sande%22";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "Daniel Furlan";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%22Daniel+Furlan%22";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Daniel+Furlan%22";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = JHud;
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = JHud;
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=JHud";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "Omg Adam Lambert";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%22Omg+Adam+Lambert%22";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Omg+Adam+Lambert%22";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "Macklemore & Ryan Lewis";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%22Macklemore+%26+Ryan+Lewis%22";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Macklemore+%26+Ryan+Lewis%22";
            }
        );
    }
)
```

Comment: "I encounter an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error." - great, **which** instance, class and selector are involved?

Comment: oh sorry, let me edit the question

Comment: The error is quite obvious. Look at the returned JSON or simpky the output of `NSLog()`. The root value of the JSON is an array, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by H2CO3 an array was returned and not a dictionary. I modified my code to this:

NSArray *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];